# Paypal webhooks no longer sending in sandbox mode

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

I used the following link to create a plan and then used the app id from my sandbox rest API panel instead of the provided one. I did this in order to receive webhooks to my backend which is totally separate at the moment. Yesterday it was working perfectly many times, and then all of a sudden it stopped sending all webhooks after a successful payment on the frontend. If I use the webhook simulator it works, and I am able debug the webhook in Laravel. I am using ngrok, in order to test it in a local environment, which also shows a full log of webhooks, so the mock ones work, but the ones from the browser dont.

**Edit:**

I created a new login, everything from zero. And below you can see the webhook event, but still not received by backend.

[image]

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=CUSTOM_APP_CLIENT_ID&vault=true" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'subscribe',
      },
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
          'plan_id': 'PLAN_ID'
        });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        alert(data.subscriptionID);
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

PayPal is attempting to send those webhooks, but they will remain 'Pending' so long as the connection to your Webhook URL listener times out or doesn't respond with a 200 level HTTP status

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I tried returning a 200 response while skipping all my logic. And the hook simulator does send them and just stays in a loop until giving it a 200. But the one from the api doesn't send anything. I sent a question to support so I will update leave a comment here when I hear back.

Comment: The 'or' is if it times out

Comment: You might be right about timing out, but I don't think its sending anything. Because it was working fine and all of a sudden stopped and never again since. Only the simulator sends something. And the screenshot is of the real hook, so it seems to be linked correctly. But i appreciate your help. I have a feeling its on their end

Comment: Pending webhooks are pending for a reason; they are attempting to send, but not able to connect and deliver

Comment: Just to get back to you, after sending a message to Paypal support, they must have done something, because without me doing anything it started working again. I think the sandbox webhooks seem unreliable. Thanks for your help anyway